# How to convert POJO to Map and vice versa in Java?

Tags: java

My use case is to convert any arbitrary POJO to Map and back from Map to POJO. So I ended up using the strategy POJO -> json -> org.bson.Document and back to org.bson.Document -> json -> POJO.

I am using gson to convert POJO to json,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String json = gson.toJson(pojo);
```

then

```
Document doc = Document.parse(json);
```

to create the document and it is easy. But other way around is problematic. `document.toJson()` is not giving standard json for long, timestamp etc and gson is complaining while deserialising to POJO. So I need a way to convert org.bson.Document to standard json.

NOTE: I want to avoid using mongo java driver or morphia as this work does not relate to mongo in anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "standard json for timestamp"? The JSON standard does not say anything about how timestamps are encoded.

Comment: Document generates json for long as {"$numberLong" : 1245} which is not parseable by gson. By standard json, I wanted to mean json like {"abc" : 1245} which can be deserialized to a field name abc.

Comment: define what you mean by *standard json* because much of what you are saying is not accurate. There is no *standard* format for a Timestamp or any other string representation of any other objects that are not raw strings, number, boolean or null.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> My use case is to convert any arbitrary POJO to Map and back from Map to POJO.

You could use Jackson, a popular JSON parser for Java:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Convert POJO to Map
Map<String, Object> map = 
    mapper.convertValue(foo, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

// Convert Map to POJO
Foo anotherFoo = mapper.convertValue(map, Foo.class);
```

According to the Jackson [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-), this method is functionally similar to first serializing given value into JSON, and then binding JSON data into value of given type, but should be more efficient since full serialization does not (need to) occur. However, same converters (serializers and deserializers) will be used as for data binding, meaning same object mapper configuration works.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Never knew it could be done by ObjectMapper, pretty much straight forward...

Comment: If you use LocalDate in your pojo for example, you'll find that the map won't contain one! You may have to customise the config...

Comment: Does this respect things like `JsonInclude` annotations?

Comment: Another possible solution using Jackson, albeit more cumbersome than suggested:
`new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(foo)).toMap()`

Answer (score 3):

even simpler, you can use [PropertyUtils.describe(Object o)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: it won't work with Map<String, Object> because it returns Map<String, String>.

Comment: you're right @HerilMuratovic, just changed to PropertyUtils.describe, which also manages complex fields like Lists, and returns Map<String, Object>.