# Jackson patch object by map

Tags: java, jackson

I have a following test code:

```
Model model = new Model();
model.setName("Alex");
model.setAddress("NY");

Map<Object, Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();
attrs.put("address", "London");
```

I need to patch my existing `model` object with only values from `attrs` `Map`.

so, after the executing the code I need to have existing `model` object with a following values:

```
name: Alex
address: London
```

Is it possible to implement with `Jackson` library ? If so, please show an example.

Comment: Convert `model` to a map, putAll, convert it back. That's not in place, but it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely can be achieved with Jackson. As [mentioned by yshavit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101109/jackson-patch-object-by-map#comment75222522_44101109), the following will do the trick:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

// Convert POJO to Map
Map<String, Object> modelAsMap = 
    mapper.convertValue(model, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}); 

// Merge maps
modelAsMap.putAll(attrs);

// Convert Map to POJO
Model modelPatched = mapper.convertValue(modelAsMap, Model.class);
```

For more details on mapping a POJO to a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and vice versa, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544594/1426227).