# Convert Java POJO to Map without JSON serialization

Tags: java

I'd like to convert a Java POJO into a Map *without* using JSON serialization for the properties (e.g. that Date's are converted to a long or a ISO8601 String). I just want the fields to be retained as they are.

For example if I have a POJO defined like this:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private Date date;
    private String x;

    public MyPojo(Date date, String x) {
        this.date = date;
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(String x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

I know I can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543926/how-to-convert-pojo-to-map-and-vice-versa-in-java) Stackoverflow question but the result is not what I want. For example if I do:

```
Map<String, Object> x = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(new MyPojo(new Date(), "x"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
System.out.println(x);
```

I get this result:

```
{date=1528521584984, x=x}
```

whereas I would simply like a Map retaining the `java.util.Date` instance without being serialized.

Note that I obviously would like this work for nested Pojo's such as:

```
public class MyPojo {
   private MyOtherPojo otherPojo;
   ...
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I've run across this a few times...

Comment: Don't think I got it to work with jackson yet.

Comment: I ended up going with apache commons BeanUtils...

Answer (score 1):

Jackson will serialize the Date to a timestamp format by default (number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, UTC). `@JsonFormat` annotation can be used to control the date format on individual classes.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private Date date;
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, going from a POJO to a `Map` seems like a bad idea.    But I guess that you have reasons for wanting to do it ...

The simple approach is to just create a `HashMap` and populate it using a sequence of `put` calls.   That gives you a map that contains the same information as the original POJO, but is not "connected" to is.

If you want the `Map` to be a view of the original POJO, there are 3rd-party libraries that can be used to do this.  For example, `org.apache.commons.beanutils` has classes for wrapping an POJO that follows the JavaBeans conventions as a `DynaBean`.  You can then adapt that as a `Map` using `DynaBeanMapDecorator`.

Mapping nested POJOs to nested maps would require more work.  (And it contradicts your requirement that you can get the value of `getData()` as a `Date` POJO rather than as a `Map`!)