# Is there a way to return custom object from database?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Let's say I have an database table `Person` with this columns:
id, name, email, and `@Entity` with same fields.

Using Spring Data Repository `findAll()` it will return me List of `Person` objects as default.
But maybe there is any way to return list of `Map` objects, where every `Map` will replace `Person` object like that:

```
Map<String, String>
key: value
id: 1
name: Mike
email: mike@gmail.com
```

Comment: You could use Jackson for that and do it in one line using Java streams: 
`List<Map<String, Object>> personsAsMaps = ...findAll().stream().map(p -> mapper.convertValue(p, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}).collect(Collectors.toList());`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544594/143531.

BTW, I agree with Kamil that it's probably **not** a good idea.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design choice. We are using ORM for mapping between objects and database relations, while map representation does not fit in the object-oriented data model. You can potentially rewrite the object into map using Jackson: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-object-to-map-example/ but it is definetely some kind of hack. What is the purpose of mapping the entity into map?

Comment: It has some @ManyToOne relationships and I don't want this objects, only ID...

Comment: Relationships are lazily-loaded by default, so you do not load them from db until you call a getter for the realtionship. If you do not need the relationship in the upper abstraction layer, you may create a DTO class for the person and map the attributes retreived from the entity

Comment: Finally i found an answer and it was pretty easy - JdbcTemplate actually do it automatically: List<Map<String, Object>> myList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from tableName");