# Java : convert POJO to map?

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is a way to convert a POJO, for example for `Person a`, the `Person` class is :

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  // getter and setter
  ....
}
```

to a map of type `Map<String, Object>` ? in which `String` is the field name and `Object` is its value.

Comment: Sure: `Map.of("name", person.getName(), "age", person.getAge())`

Comment: no, I mean it should be automatic and not manually doing this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert POJO to Map and vice versa in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543926/how-to-convert-pojo-to-map-and-vice-versa-in-java)

Comment: You can use reflection to do this. List members variables and get their values and store them in a Map.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of the link in the above comment, but the short version is to look at BeanUtils (or PropertyUtils) in Apache Commons.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You'll lose all compile time checking.