# Java : how to call all setter methods for a variable?

Tags: java

I have a Java POJO class :

```
public class Person
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  private Map<String, Object> someMap;
  // some other fields
  ...
  // setters and getters of all fields
  ...
}
```

and in my main program, I have a `Map<String, Object> map` which contains all values for a `Person person` : an example can be `map : {"name":"Tom", "age":17, "someMap":{"a"->"b"} ...}`

My question is : instead of calling setter one by one, is it possible to call all setters of object `person` and set with values in the `map` ? (because I have 200+ fields) Can it be done using reflection / Spring / Apache libraries ?

Comment: Loop over map keys and insert values matching keys to object fields names. More info here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-set-private-field-value BUT I would really consider to redesign this class.

Comment: Did you try the Jackson library as suggest in one of your last questions, when you asked to convert POJO to map? The answer in the linked question had the other way around to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39544594/7634201

Comment: `I have 200+ fields` - your first mistake

Comment: Do you mean something like `Map.putAll()`? It is not clear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description and code example what the objects and their values are, what you are trying to do and what the new values of your objects are.

Comment: If the map is used just to initialize an object, why storing it as a member?

Comment: Java reflection is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do do it by reflection I guess this could work:

```
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry :  map.entrySet()){
        Person p = new Person();
        p.getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey()).setAccessible(true);
        p.getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey()).set(entry.getClass(), entry.getValue());
        p.getClass().getDeclaredField(entry.getKey()).setAccessible(false);
    }
```